# android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity is deprecated

Tags: android

android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity is deprecated, what does this mean and how do i solve ths issue. I am new to coding.

Also 
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity. the word "ActionBarActivity" has a line across the word , why is this ?

Regards

CC

Comment: Change it to, extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: i have changed it but it says " cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity" ?

Comment: Try rebuilding your application and look to see if you have the latest versions within the the SDK Manager

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, like Eugene H points you have to update the last Support Library version.

Comment: @Eugene & Elenasys - it works ^_^. However i have another problem

Comment: “ no suitable constructor found for GestureDetectorCompat” and “private field gesturedetector is assigned but never accessed. “ what does this mean ?

Comment: @user1727257 are you calling gestureDector within your class?

Comment: i am new to coding so i am being honest i am not sure ...

Comment: this is my code import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

    private TextView ccMessage;
    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: Hey @user1727257 post another question with "no suitable constructor found for GestureDetectorCompat” and “private field gesturedetector is assigned but never accessed."   ^_^  ^_^ ^_^ ^_^ ^_^ ^_^ ^_^

Comment: i have already posted this question ^_^

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use

```
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

instead of

`android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`  **(DEPRECATED)**

and extends [**`AppCompatActivity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

```
    public myClass extends AppCompatActivity{
...
...
```

if you have the message:

> cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity

You have to update to the last **[support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)** in your `Android SDK Manager`

Answer (score 1):

The line across ActionBarActivity means that it has been deprecated. Its just another way of denoting it. You should now use AppCompatActivity instead starting with version 22.1.0.

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

This version worked for me:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the new `AppCompatActivity`. It has been deprecated because the new Toolbar was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add "import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;"
2. Delete "import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;"
3. Change "public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {"    instead of    "public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {"
4. Save the changes.

Comment: I have made the changes bu now getting the follwoing error

Answer (score 0):

just change it to `AppCompatActivity`. then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

This fill automatically do the whole process for you. the `O` is the **letter O** and **not the number**